# List of Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am new to python, I have nested list where i want to create dictionary like below using this data.

This is my input:

```
input = 
[['103.29.45.128/27', '32', 'ge', 'MPLS-LOOPBACK'], 
['100.127.0.0/23', '32', 'ge', 'MPLS-LOOPBACK'], 
['100.92.57.168/30', '', '', 'PS_S1']
]
```

The Expected output should be like below:

```
result = "prefix_set": [  
                          {
                            "prefix_entry": [
                                              {
                                                "prefix": "103.29.45.128/27",
                                                "prefix_match": "32",
                                                "prefix_condition": "ge"
                                              },
                                              {
                                                "prefix": "100.127.0.0/23",
                                                "prefix_match": "32",
                                                "prefix_condition": "ge"
                                              }
                                            ],
                            "prefix_name": "MPLS-LOOPBACK"
                          },
                          {
                            "prefix_entry": 
                                          [
                                              {
                                                "prefix": "100.92.57.168/30",
                                                "prefix_match": "",
                                                "prefix_condition": ""
                                              }  
                                          ],
                            "prefix_name": "PS_S1"
                          }
                      ]
```

Please help me to get this desired output.

I have tried this code:

```
fsm_results = [['103.29.45.128/27', '32', 'ge', 'MPLS-LOOPBACK'], 
['100.127.0.0/23', '32', 'ge', 'MPLS-LOOPBACK'], 
['100.92.57.168/30', '', '', 'PS_S1']
]


prefix_name = []
for i in fsm_results:
    prefix_name1 = i[3]
    if prefix_name1 not in prefix_name:
        prefix_name.append(prefix_name1)

temp1 = []
for i in range(0,len(prefix_name)):
    temp = {"prefix_name": prefix_name[i]} 
    for j in range(0,len(fsm_results)):
        if temp['prefix_name'] == fsm_results[j][3]:
            b = {"prefix":fsm_results[j][0],'prefix_match':fsm_results[j][1],'prefix_condition':fsm_results[j][2]}
            temp.update(b)
    temp1.append(temp)
print(temp1)
```

And i am getting output like this :

```
   [{'prefix_name': 'MPLS-LOOPBACK', 'prefix': '100.127.0.0/23', 'prefix_match': '32', 'prefix_condition': 'ge'}, {'prefix_name': 'PS_S1', 'prefix': '100.92.57.168/30', 'prefix_match': '', 'prefix_condition': ''}]
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: You should atleast try one time before asking question, if you have problem when trying, point it out and send out question, we can answer, but not likely to create code.

Comment: @edison: i have edited my question with tried code and output am getting from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited your code and getting the output as per your requirement.

```
fsm_results = [['103.29.45.128/27', '32', 'ge', 'MPLS-LOOPBACK'], 
['100.127.0.0/23', '32', 'ge', 'MPLS-LOOPBACK'], 
['100.92.57.168/30', '', '', 'PS_S1']
]

prefix_name = []
for i in fsm_results:
    prefix_name1 = i[3]
    if prefix_name1 not in prefix_name:
        prefix_name.append(prefix_name1)

temp1 = {"prefix_sets":[]}
for i in range(0,len(prefix_name)):
    temp = {"prefix_name": prefix_name[i],'prefix_entry':[]} 
    for j in range(0,len(fsm_results)):
        if temp['prefix_name'] == fsm_results[j][3]:
            b = {"prefix":fsm_results[j][0],'prefix_match':fsm_results[j][1],'prefix_condition':fsm_results[j][2]}
            temp['prefix_entry'].append(b)
    temp1["prefix_sets"].append(temp)
print(temp1)
```

The output is

```
{'prefix_sets': [{'prefix_name': 'MPLS-LOOPBACK', 'prefix_entry': [{'prefix': '103.29.45.128/27', 'prefix_match': '32', 'prefix_condition': 'ge'}, {'prefix': '100.127.0.0/23', 'prefix_match': '32', 'prefix_condition': 'ge'}]}, {'prefix_name': 'PS_S1', 'prefix_entry': [{'prefix': '100.92.57.168/30', 'prefix_match': '', 'prefix_condition': ''}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to shorten your code and just loop twice:

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)

fsm_results = [['103.29.45.128/27', '32', 'ge', 'MPLS-LOOPBACK'],  ['100.127.0.0/23', '32', 'ge', 'MPLS-LOOPBACK'],  ['100.92.57.168/30', '', '', 'PS_S1']]
for fsm in fsm_results:
    name = fsm.pop()
    item = dict(zip(['prefix', 'prefix_match', 'prefix_condition'], fsm))
    res[name].append(item)

result = {'prefix_set': [{'prefix_name': k, 'prefix_entry': v} for (k, v) in res.items()]}
print result
```

Output:

```
{'prefix_set': [{'prefix_entry': [{'prefix': '103.29.45.128/27',
                                   'prefix_condition': 'ge',
                                   'prefix_match': '32'},
                                  {'prefix': '100.127.0.0/23',
                                   'prefix_condition': 'ge',
                                   'prefix_match': '32'}],
                 'prefix_name': 'MPLS-LOOPBACK'},
                {'prefix_entry': [{'prefix': '100.92.57.168/30',
                                   'prefix_condition': '',
                                   'prefix_match': ''}],
                 'prefix_name': 'PS_S1'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):**

```
d = {}
for i in input:
    # Used setdefault method to get list of values with same index. Used zip function to group the values.
    d.setdefault(i[-1],[]).append(dict(zip(['prefix', 'prefix_match', 'prefix_condition'],i[:-1]))) 
res = {"prefix_set": [{"prefix_name":i ,"prefix_entry": v } for i, v in d.items()]}
print (res)

# Output:
{'prefix_set': [{'prefix_name': 'MPLS-LOOPBACK', 'prefix_entry': [{'prefix': '103.29.45.128/27', 'prefix_match': '32', 'prefix_condition': 'ge'}, {'prefix': '100.127.0.0/23', 'prefix_match': '32', 'prefix_condition': 'ge'}]}, {'prefix_name': 'PS_S1', 'prefix_entry': [{'prefix': '100.92.57.168/30', 'prefix_match': '', 'prefix_condition': ''}]}]}
```

I hope this counts.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using `update` instead of appending to the list in `temp`?

Some other pointers: Do not use `range(len(somthing))`. The better way is to use `enumerate(somthing)`. `enumerate` returns both the index and the item.

Always use meaningful variable names. This will help you later when you or someone else re-reads your code and tries to understand it.